Do basic Panache blocking call in pre-matching request filter
We have a pre-matching request filter, and we would like to use Panache to do some basic queries.
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

  @Inject
  MyObj myObj

  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
     if (!myObj.isAllowed()) {
       requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(403).build());
     }
  }
}

--- 

@ApplicationScoped
public class MyObjProducer {

  @Produces
  @Blocking
  @RequestScoped
  public MyObj createMyObj() {
    MyPanacheObj.find(query)....
  }
}

We're getting the error:

You have attempted to perform a blocking operation on a IO thread. This is not allowed, as blocking the IO thread will cause major performance issues with your application. If you want to perform blocking EntityManager operations make sure you are doing it from a worker thread

The documentation specifically says all pre-matching filters run non-blocking. Even if I add the @Blocking annotation to the producer method that executes the query, I still get this error. It seems to ignore the Blocking annotation, and I'm not sure how to modify the code. Any ideas how I should proceed?
We don't currently use any non-blocking code in our app. One concern I have is I've been using this same injected object throughout the rest of the app, so I'm not sure how changing this could to non-blocking would affect the rest of our blocking code.

There is no way to do this currently. I would suggest opening an issue on GitHub asking for this feature
